# qmake: execute command at the very end

Tags: qmake

How can I execute a command in qmake after **everything** is finished?

QMAKE_POST_LINK doesn't do the trick because it is executed after linking, but before qmake moves the binary to the defined directory. I need it executed when everything is already in place.

Comment: What sort of command do you want to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using QMake's [INSTALLS](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#installing-files) variable.  It creates an 'install' step in the makefile that will need to be run manually (make install), but it can both move files and execute arbitrary commands.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment and with no knowledge of qmake, my suggestion would be to simply write a short (two lines should be enough) script that runs qmake as desired and then executes your shell script.